# Android Gradle Plugin 7 LibraryBuildType no longer has isDebuggable property

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am in the process of upgrading from Android Gradle 4.1.3 to 7.0.2. One of the things I've noticed is that for my `com.android.library` module, the

```kotlin
getByName("foo") {
  ...
}
```

now has a receiver type of `LibraryBuildType` as opposed to `BuildType` that it used to. This `LibraryBuildType` no longer has the `isDebuggable` property, which `BuildType` used to have.

The [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#enable-debug) mention that

> If your app depends on a library module that you also want to debug, that library must also be packaged with `debuggable true` so it retains its debug symbols.

Obviously these docs are out of date, but what gives? Is `debuggable true` no longer needed for library modules?

I've found the [`git log` for `LibraryBuildType`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+log/b69ca9f7e7fc6289f1616baf3b7fd5675f90e450/build-system/gradle-api/src/main/java/com/android/build/api/dsl/LibraryBuildType.kt), which shows it was added around April of 2020, but I have not found any information about this in the [android gradle plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Comment: Seems valid to me that a library should allow debuggable to be set independently of any app module that might be using it.

Answer (score 3):

[image: LibraryTaskManager used libraryVariant.getDebuggable]

From what I found, the source code of `LibraryTaskManager` still uses the  `libraryVariant.getDebuggable()` that is produced from buildType&productFlavor. I'm not sure why the `debuggable` / `isDebuggable` option is not availble from `LibraryBuildType`, however if anyone is looking for the workaround, use the code below:

```
// library's build.gradle.kts
buildTypes {
    named("debug") {
        (this as com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType).isDebuggable = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet same problem, so used another workaround.

Use initWith() with debug buildType makes new type to debuggable too.

```
    create("foo") {
        // Apply debug type setting by initWith()
        initWith(getByName("debug"))
    }
```

But I think Gradle kts should add debuggable property to build type.

Answer (score -1):

I think it makes sense to remove that property for libraries, given that you should define debuggable at the application level.

Comment: that sounds reasonable, but do you have any sources showing this is the case and their documentation is wrong?